# WP_Query in a Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I am working on a wordpress project in a **child theme** of "Twenty Thirteen" main theme.

I have a page template under my "page-templates" folder.

When I run the code below, everything works just fine.

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query();
```

However, when I try to query through my custom post type like this:

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'myCustomType') );
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sub_domain/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php on line 283
```

And these are line 282, 283 and 284:

```
function autoembed( $content ) {
    return preg_replace_callback( '|^\s*(https?://[^\s"]+)\s*$|im', array( $this, 'autoembed_callback' ), $content );
}
```

I am using WordPress version 3.8.1.

Any comment and answer is appreciated.

EDIT: 
Full version of the loop

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query(  array('post_type' => 'myCustomType')  );

                // The Loop
                if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
                        //something

                    }
                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }

                // Restore original Post Data
                wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Try to increase your execution time and then check

Comment: I changed the execution time limit to 60 and it is still the same. There is just one custom post in myCustomType and normally it doesn't even take 30 seconds for normal.

Comment: No way! WP_Query don't take much time. This is something else causing it. Whats your server configuration by the way?

Comment: I don't think it is a server configuration issue. Because it works if I use parent theme for this query.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a bit more of your code. For instance, my guess is that the timeout is happening because of some issue with your loop. What do you do with $custom_query?

Comment: I added the exact copy of the loop. But it does that with loop and without loop too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never, ever forget to put this line in your loop:

```
$custom_query->the_post();
```